# No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dependencies, ninject, code-injection

What's wrong with my binding?

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IBaseRepository<User>>().To<UserRepository>();
    }
```

My IBaseRepository

```
public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        void Commit();
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        void Delete(object id);
        void Dispose();
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(object filter);
        TEntity GetById(object id);
        TEntity GetFullObject(object id);
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetPaged(int top = 20, int skip = 0, object orderBy = null, object filter = null);
        void Insert(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
    }
```

And my UserRepository

```
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User>
{
    public UserRepository(DataContext context) : base(context)
    {
        if(context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}
```

This is the error I recive 
Error activating IBaseRepository{Role}
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
 2) Injection of dependency IBaseRepository{Role} into parameter roles of constructor of type UsersController
 1) Request for UsersController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your exception message clearly states that the binding for `IBaseRepository<Role>` is missing. **Role** not **User**.

So adding

```
kernel.Bind<IBaseRepository<Role>>().To<RoleRepository>();
```

should help! ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't notice!